# Regex not matching on regexr.com - match .org not org.uk

Tags: regex

What regex would match `www.domain.org` but not `www.domain.org.uk`?

I have: `/(www.)?domain.org$`

But it doesn't match on https://regexr.com/

[image]

Comment: Your pattern [does not match `www.domain.org.uk`](https://regex101.com/r/zk2WSj/2).

Comment: No need deleting, your pattern [does not match `www.domain.org.uk`](https://regex101.com/r/zk2WSj/2).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more context. Your attempt matches `domain\.org` at end of line so technically it actually already does what you are asking.

Comment: your pattern is correct, it is matching `www.domain.org` and not matching `www.domain.org.uk`, just like you want. what's the problem?

Comment: Just stop the regex on .org and doesn't allow any character after it

Comment: Brutal down votes! @sid8491 I thought it was correct. But testing it on regexr.com it suggests it doesn't work

Comment: You forgot to turn on the multiline flag.

Comment: @DavidMasters i did not downvote it :) I have checked on regexr.com and its working fine.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ah! that makes sense - it matches now

Comment: ok as per your screenshot you are giving mult-line inputs, please enable multiline flag from right top most `flags` option

Comment: Thanks. Apologies I'm not a regex guru. Still think the down votes are harsh.

Comment: @DavidMasters yeah but that's SO. someone downvoted my answer as well.

Comment: I downvoted because it is still not clear what you are *actually* hoping to accomplish and whether the accepted answer will actually get you there. The [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) very specifically requires you to mention which regex tool you need help with, which would be a start, but in this case perhaps still not enough to give you an answer which you not only can live with, but which is useful to you and future visitors alike. For example, a firewall blocking rule needs a regex which is quite different from one you can use in a text editor.

Comment: The question was purely about why my regex wasn't matching on this web tool where I'm testing the regex before trying to use it. I don't understand why you'd need to know whether this was for a firewall or anything else. I think it is helpful for visitors who are testing out regex's but don't know about the multiline flag. I also think its clear that the answer does solve my issue. But I accept that the question is more about the testing tool/site than regex itself, but I had initially thought it *was* a problem with the regex. I will delete the question.

Comment: Scrap that - I can't delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, you just need to enable the `multiline` flag in regexr.com and it will work as expected.

[image: regex]

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the dots with a backslash because a dot in a regex matches any character like a wildcard.
Look the this `(www\.)?domain\.org$` regex at the following link.
https://regex101.com/r/1KXJqn/1